# .htaccess redirect loop issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I go to domain.com, site redirects to domain.com/en, which is expected. But then the last rule kicks in and throws it in a loop making my url look something like this:

```
http://domain.com/en/?lang=en&request=&site=basecamp&lang=en&request=&site=basecamp&lang=en&request=&site=basecamp&lang=en&request=&site=basecamp
```

**.htaccess file**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule  /([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js|eot|svg|ttf|ico|pdf))$ /$1 [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/.*
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(init\.php|content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp[L,QSA]
```

Why is the htaccess file redirecting to /?GET_VARS instead of /init.php?GET_VARS ?

And how can I avoid this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your last condition by removing the leading and trailing slashes. You've rewritten your URI to:

```
/init.php
```

But there's no trailing slash like there is in the condition that you've provided, so the rule gets applied again. It should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(init\.php|content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)
```

---

Not sure why you insist on having the trailing slash at the end of your condition here:

```
#                 with this / here, it will never match init.php --------v
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(init\.php|content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
```

But you can solve it by just excluding init.php directly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !init.php
```

So, just so it's clear, your last set of conditions/rule will look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !init.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp [L,QSA]
```

Or worst case, just add this in the very beginning of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Which prevents any kind of rewrite engine looping altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your patience so far Jon. So here's the updated rule that doesn't work: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(init\.php|content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp [L,QSA]`

Comment: I had forgotten to remove the trailing slash. But I copied and pasted the rules exactly as you wrote them out, and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: If you look at the url in my question, you'll see that it doesn't include init.php, so that's probably why `!init.php` is not working

Comment: @gAMBOOKa `!init.php` means anywhere in the URI, there cannot be an `init.php`. The URL in question is `init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp` and it most definitely contains an `init.php`

Comment: @gAMBOOKa it prevents all looping. The rewrite engine will put a URI through all the rules, and if it comes out different than it went in (e.g. if it was changed at all), the rewrite engine puts the resulting URI back through all the rules, and it'll do this forever either the URI is the same going in and coming out, or a 500 server error.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa Sorry, ran out of characters. It prevents looping because if the REDIRECT environment var is 200 (meaning that the engine looped previously already), then to exit rewriting in the current iteration *but don't change the URI at all*. So the rewrite engine will see the URI that went in is the same as the URI that came out (since it was not changed), thus the rewrite engine stops.