# htaccess redirect to parent directory - bad request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have an htaccess file to handle pretty links for a couple of folders. Some examples:

```
http://test.com/basecamp/en/foobar -> ../init.php?lang=en&request=foobar&site=basecamp
http://test.com/ravili/en/foobar   -> ../init.php?lang=en&request=foobar&site=ravili
http://test.com/ravili/ar/foo/bar  -> ../init.php?lang=ar&request=foo/bar&site=ravili
```

**Directory structure**

```
/webroot
   init.php
/webroot/basecamp
   .htaccess
/webroot/ravili
   .htaccess
```

But now, we're try to move the folders into individual domains, so instead of `http://test.com/basecamp`, we'll have `http://test-basecamp.com`

So the `.htaccess` is no longer redirecting to the init.php in the webroot, we get a 400 Bad Request and an 'Invalid URI in request GET /en/ HTTP/1.1' in the error log

**htaccess file**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule /([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|css|js|eot|svg|ttf|ico|pdf))$ /$1 [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/.*
RewriteRule !^[a-z]{2}/ /en/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ ../init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp [L,QSA]
```

So how do we go about solving this?

Comment: You can't redirect to folders outside your `webroot`!

Comment: Well, the issue is that if I move the init.php file inside the webroot, I get a redirect loop error. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427371/htaccess-redirect-loop-issue

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a rewrite base of `/` already, the `../` part of your rule's target is causing the 400 bad request (since it's attempting to traverse past the document root's parent directory). Remove the `../` from your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp [L,QSA]
```

Comment: But the .htaccess file is inside the basecamp folder, so `/` would refer to `/webroot/basecamp`. I tried this and got a redirect loop.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa `RewriteBase /` is `/webroot/`, `RewriteBase /basecamp/` is `/webroot/basecamp/`. The reason you get a rewrite loop is because you didn't fix what I suggested in your last question, specfically that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/init.php/` will **ALWAYS BE TRUE** when the URI is `/init.php?lang=etcetc`. There's no trailing slash there. It will always be true and it will always rewrite to `/init.php`, over and over and over again.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa `/` is set according to `httpd.conf`, not by the location of `.htaccess`. +1 to Lin for a good answer!

Comment: @Jon Lin: Here's the updated rule which is still throwing the redirect loop: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(init.php|content|images|css|js|fonts|pdfs)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /init.php?lang=$1&request=$2&site=basecamp [L,QSA]`

Comment: @alfasin: in httpd.conf, webroot for `test-basecamp.com` is `/webroot/basecamp`

Comment: @gAMBOOKa See your other question, this doesn't have anything to do with the 400 bad request